# How to send predicate expression?

Tags: c#, linq

I have constructor

```
class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(IReportGroup reportGroup, Func<..., bool> filter)
    {
         reportGroup.Reports.Where(filter).ToList().ForEach(r => ... )
    }
}
```

invoke: `new MyClass(reportGroup, () => reports.Where(r=>r.ID != 0))`

Comment: Where is the question? Answering such a question should give the mind reader badge...

Comment: Replace first `...` by whatever type `IReportGroup.Reports` contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit unclear, but I guess that what you want to achieve, is to pass the filter expression that is to be used within the Where method? You can do that by passing a `Func<T, bool>` where `T` is the type of object found in the list. I put together a small sample program showing this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<Person> persons = GetPersons();

        // invoke the method, passing a filter expression to be used
        PrintFiltered(persons, p => p.Name.StartsWith("F"));
    }

    private static void PrintFiltered(IEnumerable<Person> persons, Func<Person, bool> filter)
    {
        // use the expression to filter the sequence
        foreach (Person person in persons.Where(filter))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(person.Name);
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Person> GetPersons()
    {
        return new[]
            {
                new Person { Name = "Fredrik" },
                new Person { Name = "John" },
                new Person { Name = "Steven" },
            };
    }
}
```

To accept the filter in a constructor, and also have a default filter (that will return the full sequence), you can do like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    public MyClass() : this(p => true) { }

    public MyClass(Func<Person, bool> filter)
    {
        // do work
    }
}
```

Comment: Fredrik Mörk, Thank you, and how to create an empty expression ? when I do not need to filter

Comment: Just return true: `p => true`, that will cause the full sequence to be returned.

Comment: As noted by Jan, if reportGroups is `IQueryable<T>` and the desired behavior is that filtering should occur on the server then you need to pass an `Expression<Func<T,Bool>> filter`.

Comment: Fredrik Mörk,can default in the constructor?

Comment: Fredrik Mörk, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to pass the filter expression as a parameter to your constructor.
You have to pass just the lambda you wrote inside the `where` function and specify the type of your report collection elements in the parameter type definition:

```
public MyClass(IReportGroup reportGroup, Expression<Func<Report, bool>> filter)
```

And invoke it like this:

```
new MyClass(reportGroup, r => r.ID != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want -

```
  new MyClass(reportGroup, r => r.ID != 0)
```